# scrapy only downloads one image

Tags: python, scrapy

I was trying to use the ImagesPipeline to download images, and the result was that I was able to get only one picture (the last one); see the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

My target website is https://sc.chinaz.com/tupian/

You can check my code:

```
#This is spider:

import scrapy
from imgPro.items import ImgproItem
from PIL import Image


class ImgSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'img'
    #allowed_domains = ['www.xxx.com']
    start_urls = ['https://sc.chinaz.com/tupian/']


    def parse(self, response):
        div_list = response.xpath('//*[@id="container"]/div')
        # print(div_list)
        # url = 'https://sc.chinaz.com'

        for div in div_list:
            
            img_src = 'https:' + div.xpath('./div/a/img/@src2')[0].extract()
            print(img_src)

        item = ImgproItem()
        item['src'] = img_src

        
        yield item
```

Here is my pipeline:

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline

class imagePipeLine(ImagesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
       yield scrapy.Request(item['src'])

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None, *, item=None):
        imag_name = request.url.split('/')[-1]
        return imag_name

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        return item
```

What should I change to get all the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `parse()` in the for-loop, you go through the list of all images but after the loop, only the last one is saved in `img_src` and you never come back to the previous ones. So, you either need to process every image as soon as you get its respective img_src:

```
for div in div_list:        
    img_src = 'https:' + div.xpath('./div/a/img/@src2')[0].extract()
    print(img_src)
    # now process this image
```

or to save all of them in a list and process the whole list later:

```
all_img_srcs = []
for div in div_list:
    img_src = 'https:' + div.xpath('./div/a/img/@src2')[0].extract()
    print(img_src)
    all_img_srcs.append(img_src)

# now process all the images on the list
```

or maybe

```
def parse(self, response):
    div_list = response.xpath('//*[@id="container"]/div')

    items = []
    for div in div_list:            
        img_src = 'https:' + div.xpath('./div/a/img/@src2')[0].extract()
        print(img_src)
        item = ImgproItem()
        item['src'] = img_src
        items.append(item)   

    yield items
```